# can we use try with resource if we pass the resource as argument ,would that close the stream before the method called completed executing

Tags: java-io, try-with-resources

my code is below

```
try (ByteArrayInputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
previoumergeDoc.setFileMereInputStream(byteStream);
service.mergeDocument(bytestream);
```

even though im using Try with resource, i'm getting connection reset exception

Comment: What you’ve posted, is incomplete at best. It doesn’t pass a compiler. Besides that, it’s irrelevant to your question. Closing a `ByteArrayInputStream` has no effect. When you get a “connection reset exception”, you surely get it from something associated with a connection, rather than an input stream that just reads a byte array.